# How to use transaction in WSO2

Tags: sql, transactions, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I am trying to use transaction while inserting data into sql through WSO2. But transaction is not working. 
i am writing down sample code.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="InsertOrderSequence" onError="myFaultHandler">
   <log level="full"></log>
   <transaction action="new"></transaction>
<dbreport useTransaction="true">
  <connection>
     <pool>
        <dsName>jdbc/sqlserver</dsName>
     </pool>
  </connection>
  <statement>
      <sql>
           insert query 1
      </sql>
     </statement>
     <statement>
        <sql>
             insert query 2
        </sql>
     </statement>
   </dbreport> 
  <transaction action="commit"></transaction>
  </sequence>

  <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="myFaultHandler">
    <transaction action="rollback"></transaction>
  </sequence>
```

If insert happens in first table successfully and in second table not successfully, that time rollback should happen but rollback is not working and data insertion happening in first table.

please let me know where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The db report mediator does not support for the batch insert and related write operations for the database.

Since this is a batch insert to single database table, you will have to use data services features to get this done.

In WSO2 data services provides, batch insert functionality, which gives you the functionality of achieve this task.

So you can install data service features on top of ESB and create a data service with batch insert option enables as in [1]. Then call the data service from the ESB.

[1] http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.com/2014/02/wso2-dss-batch-insert-sample-end-to-end.html